# show Angular 4 project inside html div tag

Tags: html, angular, tags, project

I need to show my angular project(mentioned as http://test.com ) inside the div(.test). Is it possible to show angular project inside div  without using iframe, object and embed? .Here is my code .Any help would be amazing .Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://test.com',  //Pass URL here 
                type: "GET", //Also use GET method
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.test').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div> Div of base html</div>
    <div class="test"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `app.component.html` you can put your `<app-root></app-root>` inside what you want:

```js
<header (menuToggle)="sideMenu.toggle()"></header>
<menu [menu]="menu" #sideMenu></menu>
<div>
  <app-root></app-root>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

this is my app.component.html for example

Comment: its working fine now. it has  cross orgin issue. its solved.Thanks for your response and effort. :)

Comment: Good!  so can I ask you to close this question and vote if my answer helped you? Thanks!!